# Illegal declaration in task definition

Tags: concurrency, package, task, ada

I have the following task specification:

```ada
with Ada.Real_Time; use Ada.Real_Time;

package pkg_task is
    task type task_t is
        activationTime : constant Integer := 1;
        period : constant Integer := 2;
        computingTime : constant Integer := 1;
        startingTime : Time;
    end task_t;
end pkg_task;
```

When I compile I obtain the error mentioned on the title in all the lines of the task specification where I declare the variables, and I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jacob wrote, you can't export anything that is not an entry in tasks.
In this case, your task is really straightforward

```ada
package pkg_task is
   task type task_t;
end pkg_task;
```

In the body, you can then use your variables.

```ada
package body pkg_task is

   task body task_t is
      Activation_Time : constant Integer := 1;
      Period          : constant Integer := 2;
      Computing_Time  : constant Integer := 1;
      -- Starting_Time   : Time;
   begin
      null;
   end task_t;
end pkg_task;
```

Anyway, it would be easier if you explained us what you're trying to do.

Comment: That was it. You both solved my problem. I was just trying to do the packgage specification with no entries.

Comment: Great! I hope you start liking programming in Ada ;)

Answer (score 3):

The interface to a task is its entries, so you only declare entries in a task specification.  Any local variables in a task are declared in the declarative part of the task body.

A task without any entries is simply declared:

```ada
task Something;
```

Comment: And what if I have no entries on the task?

Comment: You then just have a body in which you declare your variables, just have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Tasking#Tasks

Comment: Do I need anyway the .ads file? because when I compile it gives me an error if it does not exist

Comment: @thmasker actually, it is rather the other way around : you cannot have a body that is not needed (by its spec, or as a "main").

Comment: Packages always need a specification, even if it is empty.

Comment: If a package specification doesn't obviously require a package body, it is not allowed to have one. - But you can force a package to need a body by putting the pragma `Elaborate_Body` in the package specification.